# PHP Class Constants Array Cast

Tags: php, arrays, casting, enums, class-constants

To simulate enums in PHP I like to use class constants.

e.g.

```
class FRUIT
{
    const apple = 1;
    const orange = 2;
    const lemon = 3;
    const pear = 4;
};
```

I have a case where I'd like cast this class to an array to populate a select list. However because class constants behave statically casting does not work e.g. `(array)(new FRUIT());` nor does the `get_object_vars()` method.

What's the best way to get round this? Do I need to create an internal function to iterate the constants and return an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I need to create an internal function to iterate the constants and return an array?

Nope! You can use Reflection to do that:

```
$r = new ReflectionClass('FRUIT');
$constants = $r->getConstants();
```

More info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/reflectionclass.getconstants.php)